# How to prop drill with type interfaces in my React Typescript counter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm making a simple counter app to track a digital card game I play. I'm passing props from my parent to my child, but the props aren't being passed. I'm thinking the fix is just put a question mark (?) at the end of the properties I'm making in the interface, but this doesn't seem optimal. The code works, I'm just repeating data in the main file and the component file, which I don't want to do.

My app.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Counter from './components/Counter'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Counter
        deckName="elusive burn"
        winPercentage={123}
        losses={6}
        wins={7}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

My Counter.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

// add a ? after the type name if you want any one of these to be optional, ex: wins?
interface Props {
  deckName: string
  wins: number
  losses: number
  winPercentage: number
}

const Counter: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const [counter] = useState<Props>({
    deckName: '',
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0,
    winPercentage: 0,
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Deck Name: {counter.deckName} </p>
      <p>wins: {counter.wins} </p>
      <p>losses: {counter.losses} </p>
      <p>Win Percentage: {counter.winPercentage}% </p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Counter
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `useState` here? You're receiving all the information you need from `props`, so take it directly from there. Then I think you'll see that there's no redundant code.

```js
// Counter.tsx
import React from 'react'

// add a ? after the type name if you want any one of these to be optional, ex: wins?
interface Props {
  deckName: string
  wins: number
  losses: number
  winPercentage: number
}

const Counter: React.FC<Props> = ({ deckName, wins, losses, winPercentage }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Deck Name: {deckName} </p>
      <p>wins: {wins} </p>
      <p>losses: {losses} </p>
      <p>Win Percentage: {winPercentage}% </p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Counter
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect.